# XSLT - for each loop on a combination of the values of two nodes

Tags: xslt

I'm trying to perform an XSL transformation on the XML below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <ns2:CommissionEvents xmlns="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes" xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager">
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121897883089643</Serial>
            </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">010035513513201121903131477120</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)">013035513513201221389170110454</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <NumberList>
            <Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)">00003551350000000907</Serial>
           </NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

The output I'm trying to achieve is something like the below. I tried for each loop grouping based on @filterValue and @format. Could someone help me achieving this using xslt 1.0 or xslt 2.0

```
<ns2:CommissionEvents>              
        <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)897883089643(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)00355135132011(21)903131477120(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
            </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
           <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(01)30355135132012(21)389170110454(17)230430(10)TLSMKTST" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="3" format="AI(01)+AI(21)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    <ns2:CommissionEvent>
            <ns0:NumberList>
            <ns0:Serial barcodeContent="(00)003551350000000907" companyPrefix="0355135" filterValue="0" format="AI(00)" />
           </ns0:NumberList>
    </ns2:CommissionEvent>
    </ns2:CommissionEvents>
```

Below is the attempt I made but did not get expected output--

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns0="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes"
                xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns0 ns2 xref">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ns2:CommissionEvents>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns2:CommissionEvents/ns2:CommissionEvent" group-by="ns2:CommissionEvents/ns2:CommissionEvent/ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@format">
          <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="ns2:CommissionEvents/ns2:CommissionEvent/ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@filterValue">
            <ns2:CommissionEvent>
                <ns0:NumberList>
                  <ns0:Serial>
                    <xsl:attribute name="barcodeContent">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@barcodeContent"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="companyPrefix">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@companyPrefix"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="filterValue">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@filterValue"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="format">
                      <xsl:value-of select="ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@format"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                  </ns0:Serial>
                </ns0:NumberList>
              </ns2:CommissionEventDetail>
            </ns2:CommissionEvent>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </ns2:CommissionEvents>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Please post your attempt so we can fix it instead of having to write your code for you from scratch. Also add the namespace declaration to your input to make it well-formed XML.

Comment: @michael, I updated the requirement as you have asked. Please help me to achieve the output.

Comment: The context item for the inner group-by is an `ns2:CommissionEvent` so you should remove the first two steps in the path expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want, at least in terms of the grouping, something along the following lines:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns:ns0="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes"
                xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns0 ns2">
  
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="/ns2:CommissionEvents/ns2:CommissionEvent" group-by="ns0:NumberList/ns0:Serial/@format">
          <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()/ns0:NumberList" group-by="ns0:Serial/@filterValue">
                <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()/*"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>            
          </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Martin, value is coming now but with not proper order. Could you please help with Michael 2nd stylesheet he has shared. In Michael 2nd stylesheet, proper order is coming but with empty value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns2="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:serialized_operations_manager"
xpath-default-namespace="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes"
xmlns:ns0="urn:tracelink:mapper:sl:canonical:commontypes">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/ns2:CommissionEvents">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="ns2:CommissionEvent" group-by="NumberList/Serial/concat(@filterValue, '|', @format)">
            <ns2:CommissionEvent>
                <ns0:NumberList>
                    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                        <ns0:Serial> 
                            <xsl:copy-of select="NumberList/Serial/(@*|text())"/>
                        </ns0:Serial> 
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ns0:NumberList>
            </ns2:CommissionEvent> 
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this does require a processor that supports XSLT 2.0 (your stylesheet is tagged as `version="1.0"` even though it uses `xsl:for-each-group`).

Comment: Hi Michael, using above xslt I am getting correct order but with empty value under the tags. Could you please check and help.

Comment: HI Michael, using your 2nd stylesheet I am able to get expected order but serial tags are coming with empty value. Could you please look into this and help. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Try the edited version.

Comment: I tried the edited version but still getting empty value only under tags. Just for your reference pasting here a portion of output. <NumberList>
        <Serial></Serial>
        <Serial></Serial>
      </NumberList>

Comment: I am getting a different result: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qtiBoq/1

Comment: Thank you so much Michael, found the mistake I was doing. Thanks again for your help.